# Как выполнить два запроса MySQL одновременно?

Tags: php, mysql

Требуется получить информацию из первой таблицы, а потом подставить полученную информацию в WHERE второго запроса.

Что-то типа этого:

```
SELECT a FROM b UNION SELECT c FROM d WHERE c = a
```

**a** в конце это результат **а** из первого запроса.
Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Смотрите `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: приведите лучше пример данных, какие у вас есть, и что хотите получить в итоге

Comment: Варианты: JOIN двух таблиц, WHERE IN либо WHERE EXISTS с подзапросом.

Comment: если первый запрос возвращает одно значение, то и `where = ` может быть

Comment: @And Спасибо, проблема решена.